# Interoperating Java and Powershell

Tags: java, powershell

Suppose I wanted to create a Powershell commandlet in a non-Microsoft language, in this case Java.

Obviously, this would be a simple task in e.g. C# - but I have not found any documentation that shows how (or even confirms if it is possible) to integrate other languages.

I do not mean calling the Java executables from Powershell (`java -jar Thing.jar` or similar), I would like it to behave identically to a "native" Powershell commandlet - pipelining, get/set properties, etc. - all the Java-ness should be hidden from powershell.

So: Does there exist any shim layer / libraries / other method for exposing Java code natively as a Powershell commandlet?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Have added question to end of post, hopefully this makes sense. 

I'm sure it would be possible... but whether it is practically possible is another issue.

Comment: Do you want to use java code or classes from jar file in powershell script ? If you just looking for some java based scripting language you can check out Groovy or Kotlin Script.

Comment: I want to extend Powershell with commandlets, that are written in Java and can make use of all the Java standard libraries, load 3rd party jars from classpath (e.g. jsoup - just as an example, I'm aware of the built in powershell commandlets for connecting to web services), etc. . My automation platform uses powershell scripts, so I do not want to run a different scripting language.

If whatever solution happens to be compatible with other JVM languages that would be nice, but I don't use them personally so Java only solutions are fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option in your case would be IKVM. That tool converts Java byte code to CLR byte code, so basically if you have jar or class file you can convert it to dll, and than add it to you powershell script (or C# code). They already converted Java’s standard library, so you just need to try to convert your jar. There is no guaranty it will work, especially with some newer libraries, but chances are good. I was able to convert several jdbc drivers and use them in powershell

https://www.ikvm.net/

Below is an example (connecting to Oracle database):

```
# Download an extract IKVM to any folder
# cd C:\temp\ikvm\bin\
# convert jar to dll with ikvmc: ikvmc -target:library C:\jdbc\ojdbc6.jar


Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\ikvm\bin\ojdbc6.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\ikvm\bin\IKVM.OPenJDK.Jdbc.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\ikvm\bin\IKVM.OPenJDK.Core.dll"

$url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/someServiceName"
$driver = [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]::new()
$props = [java.util.Properties]::new()
$props.setProperty("user", "someUser")
$props.setProperty("password", "somePassword")
$conn = $driver.connect($url, $props) 
$cmd = $conn.createStatement()

$r = $cmd.executeQuery("select * from all_tables where rownum < 20")
Write-Host "column count: $($r.getMetaData().getColumnCount())"

while($r.next()){

$row = foreach($c in 1..20){ $r.getString($c)}
Write-Host ($row -join "|")
}
```

Another option is to use JVM api. Looks like the only free tool for that is [Jni4net](http://jni4net.com/). It converts your jars into proxies (dlls) you can use in you .net project to interact with JVM. So you need Java installed to make it work. I was able to build their sample apps, but couldn’t generate  proxy for any jdbc I was working with. You can give it a chance, but I think it's much less reliable than the first option. First of all download binaries and than follow the instruction to generate a proxy:
https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/wiki/Generating-Proxies

If non of the above works, than explore Jython, Groovy, etc.

Also, creating a wrapper for “java -jar myJar ...” is not that bad option to my mind. If your java app is printing results to standard output it shouldn’t be a problem to integrate it with cmdlets and use all the PS syntactic sugar you need. 
Below is the example of wrapping this jdbc [tool](http://jdbcsql.sourceforge.net/) as a cmdlet:

```
function Invoke-Jdbc { param(
  $java="Java" # or path to java exe 
, $format="EXCEL"
, $driver = "C:\jdbc\jdbcsql.zip"
, $dbtype, $hostname, $port, $db, $user, $password, $query
)

$data = &$java -jar $driver -f $format -m $dbtype -host $hostname -port $port -d $db -U $user -P $password $query
Write-Output -NoEnumerate ($data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" | Out-DataTable)

}


$oracle = @{ 
 dbtype = "oracle"
 hostname = "localhost"
 port = "1521"
 db = "ServiceNameOrSID"
 user = "user"
 password = "password"
 query = "select owner, table_name from all_tables"
}

$dt = Invoke-JDBC @oracle
```

Comment: It's a shame this doesn't support newer versions of Java and seems kind of abandoned, but this looks like the best option for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they stopped development few years ago. Btw, the download link on the main page does not refer to the latest version. The last version was 8.1